# Statistically Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Problem:

> For the statistically independent random variables $X$ and $Y$
>   with $f_X(x)=1$, $1\leq x\leq 2$, and $f_Y(y)=e^{-(y-1)}$, $
> 1\leq y< \infty$, determine $f_Z(z)$ where $Z=X+Y$.

I couldn't find a starting point for this question. I tried to product $f_X(x)$ with $f_Y(y)$ but nothing showed up. Could you please give me direction to start?

Comment: Welcome to our site!  Do you know about "convolution"?

Comment: My instructor gave me the formulas but didn't teach how to apply to a problem. The problem is I know the subjects but couldn't recognize which formula and technique to use on solving a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and continuous random variables with density functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$, the density function of a random variable $X+Y$ is given by
$$
f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\mathrm dy.
$$
The function $f_{X+Y}$ is called the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$.

Consider the first integral. $f_X(x)\ne0$ if $1\le x\le2$ and $f_Y(z−x)\ne0$ if $z−x\ge1$. Hence, $f_X(x)f_Y(z−x)\ne0$ if $1\le x\le\min\{z−1,2\}$ and we need to calculate the integral 
$$
\int_1^{\min\{z−1,2\}}f_X(x)f_Y(z−x)\mathrm dx
$$
in order to obtain $f_{X+Y}(z)$ for $z\ge2$. By using [Integral Calculator](http://integrals.wolfram.com/) to find the antiderivative, we obtain
$$
\int_1^{\min\{z−1,2\}}f_X(x)f_Y(z−x)\mathrm dx=e^{\min\{z-1,2\}-z+1}-e^{2-z}
$$
for $z\ge2$. Hence,
$$
f_{X+Y}(z)=
\begin{cases}
1-e^{2-z},&\text{if } 2\le z<3;\\
e^{3-z}-e^{2-z},&\text{if } z\ge3.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Are the boundaries of X and Y important because X is bound to 1 and 2?

Comment: Then am I wrong for doing two integrals, one from 1 to two and one from 2 to infinite and summing these two integral results?

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question, how could I determine min{z−1,2} or can I make the integral with this variable. I'm a little bit confused about integrals and will be grateful if you help me.

Comment: @V.C.,Taking the first convolution integral,$ f_X(x) = 1 $ for $1<x<2$, o otherwise, transforming the interval interms of y we get $1<z-y<2$, $z-2<y<z-1$.  Hence $f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{z-2}^{z-1} e^{-(y-1)}dy.$  Would it be right now.

Comment: @YeşimDokuz I updated my answer.

Comment: @satishramanathan If $z=4$, then $\int_{z-2}^{z-1}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\mathrm dx=\int_2^3f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\mathrm dx=0$, which is not correct.

Comment: @V.C. I'm thankful to you to show me how to go step by step.

Comment: @YeşimDokuz You're welcome!